# return the status of par("xaxt") in use in an R plotting function

Tags: r, plot

I expect my function `foo` to return the status of `par("xaxt")` in use. In my example of use, I define `xaxt = "n"` and no x-axis is drawn BUT my function still returns the status of par(`xaxt`) as `"s"`!

How can I have my function correctly return the status of `par("xaxt")` in use?

```
foo <- function(x, y = NULL, ...){

  plot(x = x, y = y, ...)
  par("xaxt")             # should return the "xaxt" in use
 }

# Example of use:
foo(1, xaxt = "n")        # the "xaxt" in use is "n" but function return "s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you never set `par`. You pass an argument to `plot` which temporarily overrides the `par('xaxt')` setting, but it never actually sets `par('xaxt')`.

So your code does the correct thing: try creating another plot without passing an `xaxt` argument to it: you’ll get an x-axis.